# Making search facility

Tags: php, search, full-text-search

I want to make a search facility in my website.I'm using php..
What criteria should be taken for searching.
For ex: if someone searches

```
How to make soap
```

I can use many approaches for the search like finding database entries having exactly the same search string
or finding the database entries in the order of search keywords(ie . entry with search string "How" +"Soap" will have less preference than entry having search string "how soap make")...

So what is the algorithm generally used for searching.?

Also what is meant by full text search?

Comment: Text searches will sometimes use _weighting_ systems to determine the relevance of terms based on their usual frequency ("the" isn't very useful, for example). Equally the presence of word combinations can change the meaning (and hence may add extra terms in the background to adjust the search results). For example "make soap" versus "soap server" - here the word "soap" means very different things. Start off by looking at things like Solr and Lucene, as they're optimised for text searching.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a big subject for a simple answer, but I think what you mean is how to run complex fulltext searches on MySQL. In other words, this is really a MySQL question, not a PHP one.

Basically, you need to:
1. Create a fulltext index on a text field in your database.
2. Run queries on that database field using MySQL's fulltext syntax.

The basic syntax for querying a fulltext indexed table in MySQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
     WHERE MATCH (fulltextfield)
     AGAINST ('my search phrase');
```

There's a lot more to it than that, but the MySQL documentation is the place to go: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

If you want to do really advanced fulltext searches, a good recommendation is [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), but that's probably way more advanced than you need.